# Record more than two external mics with Tascam DR-40 into separate tracks

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, mixer, tascam

Tascam DR-40 has two external mic inputs. I believe I can record two stereo tracks on each input. I've been plugging in an XLR microphone into each of the two inputs and recording a podcast with two people. Then adjusting the audio in post.

But now we have a third person. I would like to add a third mic such that I get a separate (mono) track recorded for them as well. I imagine it's possible to "split" one of the inputs to the DR-40 such that one mic records to the left channel, and the second  to the right channel. Is it possible? What's the (physically) smallest device that can achieve that? I know a mixer probably can, but that requires dragging around a mixer.

Sorry, I'm a total beginner to this. Because the podcast is on the move, I'm looking for the smallest solution. [Here's the podcast](http://takeituneasy.com/) (one episode is up) if you want to listen to the sound. It's taped in a gym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DR-40 is a four track recorder, but only if you count the two built-in mics.  You can have at most, two external microphones.  BTW, XLR inputs are inherently mono.

> Record the built-in microphones ***with*** the XLR mic or line input for a
>   four-track recording

<sub>Emphasis mine.  [From the website](http://tascam.com/product/dr-40/overview/)</sub>

I think it will still suffice in your three source situation however.

I would hand an external mic to both of your guests, and use the built-in mic yourself as the third.  At least that way, *you* will be the one in control of the recording unit.